# Upoaded image's too big : a circular reference occurs

Tags: forms, file-upload, symfony4, circular-reference

I'm trying to build a subscription form with Symfony4 and I tought it was working but it appears that when I try to upload a profile picture that is too big, I've got the following error :
A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class "App\Entity\User" (configured limit: 1)

However I did set a constraint on my property `profilePicture` regarding the file's maxSize the user will try to upload so I do not understand why this is happening (I've got all the other errors displaying well).

Here is the part of code regarding the property profilePicture :

```php
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Merci de bien vouloir sélectionner une image")
     * @Assert\Image(
     *     minRatio="1",
     *     maxRatio="1",
     *     minWidth="250",
     *     minHeight="250",
     *     minRatioMessage="Votre photo de profil doit avoir un ratio de 1:1",
     *     maxRatioMessage="Votre photo de profil doit avoir un ratio de 1:1",
     *     minWidthMessage="Votre image doit faire minimum {{ minWidth }} de large",
     *     maxWidthMessage="Votre image doit faire minimun {{ minHeight }} de hauteur", 
     *     maxSize="2M",
     *     maxSizeMessage="Votre image ne peut pas fait plus de 2M")
     */
    private $profilePicture;
```

The HomeController dealing with the subscription form :

```php
/**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function index(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder): Response
    {
        //To Manage registration
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && !$form->isValid()) {
            return $this->json([
                "status" => "error(s)",
                "errors" => $form->getErrors(true, true)
            ], 200);
        }
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // move the file from the temp folder
            $fileUploader = new FileUploader($this->getParameter('profile_pictures_directory'));
            $profilePicture = $form['userProfile']['profilePicture']->getData();
            if ($profilePicture) {
                $profilePictureFilename = $fileUploader->upload($profilePicture);
                $user->getUserProfile()->setProfilePicture($profilePictureFilename);
            }
            // encode the plain password
            $user->setPassword(
                $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );
            $user->setCreationDate(new \DateTime());

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            // do anything else you need here, like send an email

            return $this->json(["status" => "success"]);
        }

        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

The FileUploader service :

```php
<?php
namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class FileUploader
{
    private $targetDirectory;

    public function __construct($targetDirectory)
    {
        $this->targetDirectory = $targetDirectory;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $originalFilename = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $safeFilename = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [^A-Za-z0-9_] remove; Lower()', $originalFilename);
        $fileName = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        try {
            $file->move($this->getTargetDirectory(), $fileName);
        } catch (FileException $e) {

        }

        return $fileName;
    }

    public function getTargetDirectory()
    {
        return $this->targetDirectory;
    }
}
```

There is a OneToOne relation between the entity User and the entity UserProfile where complementary data regarding the User are stored.

I'd like this to simply display the error message regarding the file size like it does for all the other types of errors.
Let me know if you need other parts of my code.

Comment: your error `A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class "App\Entity\User"` actually indicates, that *something* is trying to serialize the **`User`**, which then causes problems. adding an image *might* have that effect at some point. In any case, you should take a look at how symfony stores sessions (because it causes the `User` to be serialized). If the problem persists, let us know. (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#understanding-how-users-are-refreshed-from-the-session)

Comment: After a few digging I've figured out that it's `$form->getErrors(true, true)` that causes this problem. However, I do not have a clue how to solve it cause I need my error to be returned as json in order to be able to display them.

Comment: `$form->getErrors(true,true)` returns an iterator, which you can just loop over in a foreach loop. which you should probably do to fill an array with just some error messages or something, which you then return. the form errors that are available usually contain references to the form and its content, which are serialized, if you just pass it into your output without "rendering" it first.

Comment: That's the problem. When I try to read the value of `$form->getErrors(true,true)` the page begin a never ending loading...So a loop over cannot solve my problem right now...

Comment: with "try to read" you probably mean `var_dump` or `var_export` or `print_r`, all of which handle this problem poorly. try `dd($form->getErrors(true,true))` for development cases, so you can have a look at the structure.

Comment: If I use dump() or even dd() it just returns me : 'Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "stream_socket_sendto():...'

Comment: the rest of the error message may actually be helpful ;o)

Comment: I try my best to translate the message as I work in french : `stream_socket_sendto(): A send request or a receveid data request was not authorized because the socket is not connected and (while sending on a datagram socket using sendto call) no adress is given.`

Comment: I'm really confused as to why a `dump` call and specifically a `dd` call would even remotely trigger a `stream_socket_sendto` call... okay, let's try something different: use `$formerrors = array_map(function($e) { return $e->getMessage(); }, $form->getErrors(true,true));` and then use `$formerrors` in your response for `'errors' => $formerrors,`

Comment: Helas, it's not working either : `Warning: array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, object given` (Thank you so much for your help so far !)

Comment: array_map is acting up XD. okay, `$formerrors=[]; foreach($form->getErrors(true, true) as $e) { $formerrors[] = $e->getMessage(); }` and then, as before.

Comment: I get the messages that way but that's not the only info I need (I need also the name of the input that throw the error). The circular reference really occurs only when I try to upload an image that's too big....that's really strange

Comment: I assume it's because some validator on the image maybe references something internally in the error object. try (in the foreach): `$formerrors[$e->getOrigin()->getName() ?? null] = $e->getMessage();`

Comment: It works ! :D https://imgur.com/a/XcpmoGE 
I'm just so confused about the reason why I was not working on the first place. Could'nt find any explanation elsewhere.

Comment: the dead giveaway is that it hangs when you call one of the usual suspects (`var_dump`, `print_r`) on a variable. This usually means, that the variable *somewhere* contains a complex object - like a reference to doctrine's entity manager, which contains references to all entities, which contain references to the entity manager and so on. That's why it takes an eternity to output. Usually `dump`/`dd` will manage *way* better, but your setup is probably "in the way" for it to work properly. I usually don't like giving the full solution, so something can be learned ;o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it turns out, the form produces errors, and at least one of the errors has a complex object inside, which introduces recursion into the json encoding process*:

```
        return $this->json([
            "status" => "error(s)",
            "errors" => $form->getErrors(true, true)
        ], 200);
```

to prevent this from happening, it's preferable to prepare the errors to be shown:

```
$formerrors = [];
foreach($form->getErrors(true, true) as $error) {
    $fieldname = ($origin = $error->getOrigin()) ? $origin->getName() : null;
    if($fieldname) {
        $formerrors[$fieldname] = $error->getMessage();
    } else {
        $formerrors[] = $error->getMessage();
}
return $this->json([
    "status" => "error(s)",
    "errors" => $formerrors,
], 200);
```

since an error can have *no* origin but the form itself, the condition in the loop *might* be necessary. also: for deep nested forms, it might be necessary to improve the approach.

As a side note: the returned status code (`200` in your case) is not okay and it should be something in the 400s, since the request produced error, the response should not be 200 ("OK").

*) for anyone wondering how to notice: it usually takes ALL of the 30s standard execution time until a timeout occurs. and if the standard execution time is set to be unlimited, the whole computer may freeze because it slowly (or very quickly) eats up all the memory to prepare an infinitely long answer. this almost always happens when `var_dump`ing or `print_r`ing complex objects that in their references (possible multiple layers deep) reference the complex objects or each other, creating an infinite loop as the serialization process follows references deeper into the objects. `dump` as well as `dd` (symfony debug output) will usually perform *way* better (recursion is avoided) and thus allow inspection of the object. - however, both `dd` and  `dump` should not be used in production, also the debug component is by default disabled in prod env.